# finding convolutions graphically

Tags: convolution

So I just started learning convolution. I'm doing some homework and I just wanted to know if I'm on the right track. We're meant to find convolutions graphically in thsi question, this is what it looks like:

[image]

This was my answer:

[image]

Here's how I solved it:

[image: My solution]

Comment: @Moo I really like your notes. Do you mean drawing it using something like matlab? I would but matlab isn't working for me and I don't know any other software that does it as good. That's why I asked the question here

Comment: @Moo okay, will do that now. Thanks

Comment: Don't think I'll be able to plot it. I'm having problems remembering how to write the code. I had a script written by instructor that i used and tweaked but I don't have access to it cause matlab is having some problems on my side.

Comment: @Moo Sorry i took too long too respond. Here's a rough sketch of what it looks like [link](http://imgur.com/8IP0veK)

Comment: okay, sure @Moo